# Servlet throws exception on cast of session.getAttribute

Tags: java, servlets

Anyone knows why the code throw an exception on this line?

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        UserFactory userFactory = UserFactory.getInstance();
        int userNum = (int)session.getAttribute("userID");
        User user = userFactory.getUserByID(userNum);
```

Exactly on the third line, I used this lines of code other times in the project but never had this exception.

Comment: Didn't work, and NetBeans suggest me to change it with a cast Integer.parseInt((String) session.getAttribute("userID"));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Although you saved an int, method expects an Object. Therefore, your int will become an Integer (read on auto-boxing). Below should work fine!

int userid = (Integer) session.getAttribute("userID");

Comment: It always stopped there, throwing an exception java.lang.NullPointerException.
When I'm logged in the JSP shows the page correctly, but if I'm not don't.
So I think the problem is not the cast, but something else

Comment: session.getAttribute("userID") should be returning null. check if you have specified the attribute name properly. Further, Make sure that you have a try catch to check if it is a null object

Comment: Just checked, userID is null. Thank you.